# Pass an Empty String into Int

Tags: python

How do I pass an empty string into int in the language of Python? The code snippet listed below generated a ValueError. I apologize if this has been covered already. Did not have much time to search for it. Thanks! :)

```
num1 = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing the fact that empty string evaluates to False:

```
num1 = int(input('Enter a number: ') or 0)
```